# Packages are not available under 13.04?

Tags: apt, software-center, package-management

I have a small problem with installing packages under Ubuntu 13.04.

Yesterday I wanted to install "pdfshuffler" (https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/pdfshuffler/).

If I go to the Ubuntu Software Center and look for "pdfshuffler" there is one item in the list (the package I want to install). When I click once on this item, the install button does not appear. If I then on furter information a error message appears telling me that there is no package called pdfshuffler in my package sources.

I tried to install other packages like Eclipse or Supertux but nothing works.

Why can't Ubuntu find these packages?

Best regards, Sven...

Comment: it works on my 64-bit version of 13.04, are you using the 32-bit or the 64-bit version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I just went to Ubuntu Software Center, and installed Pdfshuffler.

[image]

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and try installing again fro USC.  Also try

```
sudo apt-get install pdfshuffler
```

And see if it works, and let me know.

Comment: When I execute the first command I get

0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.

That means the it did not change anything. So the second command does not work as well.

Comment: Can you add the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`.  Do you get any error messages when running the second command?

Answer (score 0):

When Ubuntu's package manager goes to install an application, it looks through a bunch of sources (where the packages are being kept and maintained). It sounds like you don't have the proper source listed, so it can't install the package. Do a google search for your program's development page and you can probably get the source (ppa:something/something) off their website with instructions, or even be able to download the .deb package directly.